# How to share APC cache between several PHP processes when running under FastCGI?

Tags: php, fastcgi, apc, mmap

I'm currently running several copies of PHP/FastCGI, with APC enabled (under Apache+mod_fastcgi, if that matters).  Can I share cache between the processes?  How can I check if it's shared already?  (I think the `apc.mmap_file_mask` ini setting might be involved, but I don't know how to use it.)

(One of the reasons I think its *not* shared at the moment is that the `apc.mmap_file_mask`, as reported by the apc.php web interface flips between about 3 different values as I reload.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

APC does **not** currently share its cache between multiple php-cgi workers running under fastcgi or fcgid. See [this feature request](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=11988) for details: "this behaviour is the intended one as of now".

One workaround is to allow PHP to manage its own workers. You can do this using the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in your wrapper script (plenty of examples all over the web for that). You should also stop fastcgi/fcgid from spawning more than one PHP process if you want to use this method.

The disadvantage with PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN is that its management of the workers is not as good as that provided by fcgid/fastcgi.

So, there we are. APC in a fcgid/fastcgi environment means giving each PHP worker their own cache, or disabling fcgid/fastcgi's process spawning in favor of PHP's built-in management. Let's hope this changes in the future.

Comment: According to another comment, to configure mod_fastcgi to only start up one instance of php-cgi (so that php-cgi itself handles the workers, and hence share cache), is with "FastCgiConfig -maxClassProcesses 1" in the httpd.conf.  See also http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html.

Comment: Bug #57825 has been closed. Does PHP support it now?

Comment: FPM supports it, and has deprecated most fcgid/fastcgi-based solutions. APC still has occasional issues with locks (contention, deadlocks) when you share it between workers in a large pool, but it works pretty well (and *very* well for file/opcode caching), and FPM has built-in safeties (segfault detection) for when APC does stuff up. (Although, it doesn't help for deadlocks.)

Answer (score 10):

While it's not perfect the method Domster suggested is the best.  I've been doing this for a short time on some low volume sites without errors.  I wrote up a detailed explanation on [how to set up mod_fastcgi with a shared opcode cache](http://www.brandonturner.net/blog/2009/07/fastcgi_with_php_opcode_cache/) last night.

I found it very important to use mod_fastcgi rather than the newer mod_fcgid because mod_fcgid will only send one request at a time to the PHP process regardless of how many children PHP has spawned via PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN.

Comment: Great answer! It also helped me solve my concurrency problem with `mod_fcgid`!

Comment: great article! see also http://whorka.github.com/blog/2012/02/08/apache-mod_fastcgi-suexec-php-apc-rhel.html

Answer (score 0):

The cache should be shared between processes. You should be seeing the same value for the mmap file between phpinfo() and apc.php invocations. It is working for me with the suggested default APC configuration settings:

```
extension="apc.so"
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.shm_size=128
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.mmap_file_mask="/tmp/apc.XXXXXX"
apc.enable_cli=1
```

You may want to post your settings. I've seen warnings that the mmap_file_mask must be exactly one of the values they allow. So if you are missing one of those Xs there is no telling what you will get.

Maybe it involves your fastcgi+apache configuration.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think it's actually working for you. If you refresh pages, you'll usually be served by the same php-cgi worker for whatever reason (KeepAlive perhaps?), especially (and I'm not saying this is the case) if your server isn't under a whole heap of load.