# How to find apc.php file location?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, apc

I have installed *APC* cache on *AWS Elastic Beanstalk* and its installed (I confirmed it by phpinfo() )

How do i check APC is working or not? How to find apc.php file location ?

Thanks

Comment: In which os you have installed PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this command in a terminal :

```
find / -name apc.php
```

Comment: Thank you so much i found it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute

`find / -name apc.php* 2>/dev/null`

and

`locate apc.php`

to find location of apc.php

also refer [How to make APC (PHP Cache) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495619/how-to-make-apc-php-cache-work) for apc-php-cache working